# Replacing spaces with underscores in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm trying to use this code to replace spaces with _, it works for the first space in the string but all the other instances of spaces remain unchanged. Anybody know why?

```
function updateKey()
{
    var key=$("#title").val();
    key=key.replace(" ","_");
    $("#url_key").val(key);
}
```

Answer (score 901, accepted):

Try `.replace(/ /g,"_");`

*Edit*: or `.split(' ').join('_')` if you have an aversion to REs

*Edit*: [John Resig said](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/):

> If you're searching and replacing
>   through a string with a static search
>   and a static replace it's faster to
>   perform the action with
>   .split("match").join("replace") -
>   which seems counter-intuitive but it
>   manages to work that way in most
>   modern browsers. (There are changes
>   going in place to grossly improve the
>   performance of .replace(/match/g,
>   "replace") in the next version of
>   Firefox - so the previous statement
>   won't be the case for long.)

Comment: Had it in my clipboard anyway. What are the odds.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without the regexp?

Comment: regex: now you have TWO problems! ha ha. Actually, this is one area where plain old split/join might be a better choice, especially if the codebase will be shared amongst less-than-expert peers who may need to poke through things without you to guide them.

Comment: Reason why the people who answered did not use /\s/g ?

Comment: Wouldn't the split/join solution generate a lot of overhead, allocating and deallocating many strings where the solution could just run in-place?

Comment: Instead of `/ /g` use `/\ /g` - both work in Javascript. The latter works in CoffeeScript also.

Comment: As of 2015 is `.replace(/ /g,"_");` faster than `.split(' ').join('_')`.

Comment: Future people browsing this @Inez has a link to test both speeds of split/join VS. replace. As of late 2018 replace is significantly faster.

Comment: Still using .replace in 2021

Comment: Still using .replace in 2022

Comment: Even though question is specifically asking to replace space as character 0x32, there are other `white space` characters too such as tab, 0xA0 (non-breaking space, I believe?) which would be nice if included in answer

Answer (score 99):

try this:

```
key=key.replace(/ /g,"_");
```

that'll do a global find/replace

[javascript replace](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Beautiful code!!! That did it!!!

Answer (score 73):

To answer Prasanna's question below:

> How do you replace multiple spaces by
>   single space in Javascript ?

You would use the same function `replace` with a different regular expression.  The expression for whitespace is `\s` and the expression for "1 or more times" is `+` the plus sign, so you'd just replace Adam's answer with the following:

```
key=key.replace(/\s+/g,"_");
```

Answer (score 57):

You can try this

```
 var str = 'hello     world  !!';
 str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

It will even replace multiple spaces with single '-'.

Comment: Probably noteworthy: This does also strip tabs other whitespace.

Answer (score 21):

Replace **spaces with underscore**

```
var str = 'How are you';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('_');
```

**Output:** How_are_you

Answer (score 19):

I created JS performance test for it http://jsperf.com/split-and-join-vs-replace2

Comment: it seems nowadays replace is the better overall choice

Comment: Kave - what?  Although not all browsers are equal, split/join on average is much better.  In fact, in a lot of modern browsers, it's a tone better!  Thanks Inez for setting this up!

Comment: A little over a year later now and running that above test in Chrome 32.0.1700.107 .. str.replace() yields far better results (64% faster)

Answer (score 8):

## Replace all occurrences

This is happening because `replace()` method is designed this way to replace only the first occurance **when you use string to find the match**. Check the replace method.

To replace all matches you can **use the following 3 methods**:

1. ### use regex with the global flag in `replace()` method:

   When you use the `replace` method with regex with `/g` flag it replaces all the matching occurrences in a string.

   ```js
       function updateKey()
       {
           var key=$("#title").val();
           key=key.replace(/ /g,"_");
           $("#url_key").val(key);
       }
       // Show case
       let title = "Your document title";
       console.log(title.replace(/ /g,"_"));
   ```
2. ### Using replaceAll method:

   The `replaceAll` method will remove all spaces with an underscore. (must use the global flag with it
   when using regex)

   ```js
       function updateKey()
       {
           var key=$("#title").val();
           key=key.replaceAll(/ /g,"_");
           // key=key.replaceAll(" ","_"); also valid
           $("#url_key").val(key);
       }
       // Show case
       let title = "Your document title";
       console.log(title.replaceAll(/ /g,"_"));
   ```
3. ### Use a combination of `split` and `join` method:

   Split your string at spaces and join it by using _ as a separator in the join method.

   ```js
       function updateKey()
       {
           var key=$("#title").val();
           key=key.split(" ").join("_");
           $("#url_key").val(key);
       }
       // Show case
       let title = "Your document title";
       console.log(title.split(" ").join("_"));
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Just using `replace`:

```js
var text = 'Hello World';
    
new_text = text.replaceAll(' ', '_');
    
console.log(new_text);
```

Comment: This will just replace the first space not after that

Comment: This answer should be removed as the OP tried that and it failed.

Comment: With replaceAll this does work. (Method is only not supported in IE.)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but I didn't see anyone mention extending the String `prototype`.

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replace){
    if(!search || !replace){return this;} //if search entry or replace entry empty return the string
    return this.replace(new RegExp('[' + search + ']', 'g'), replace); //global RegEx search for all instances ("g") of your search entry and replace them all.
};
```

Comment: You didn't see anyone do it as it's a terrible idea.
[Check out this other SO question for more.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const updateKey = key => console.log(key.split(' ').join('_'));
updateKey('Hello World');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('#title').keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#url_key').val(value.split(' ').join('_'));
    }).keyup();
});
```

-- or you can use:

```
$(function() {
    $('#title').keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#url_key').val(value.replace(/ /g,"_"));
    }).keyup();
});
```