# How do I replace an asterisk in Javascript using replace()?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Using JQuery, I'm extracting the value from what is essentially a query box for some data in a MySQL database. Knowing that most users will use an '*' (asterisk) as a wildcard value and that MySQL uses the '%' character, I want to convert any asterisks to '%'.

Normally, this would just be as simple as using

```
queryString = inputText.replace('*', '%');
```

but I've had little success with that. Javascript's `replace()` function only replaces the first occurrence, so it's not replacing the last asterisk in something like `*Foo*`

The second option I tried was using a regular expression, which also didn't work:

```
queryString = inputText.replace(/\x2a/g, '%');
```

How can I replace the '*' (asterisks) with a  '%' (percent sign)? I'd imagine there's a really simple regular expression, or something I'm overlooking.

Comment: Actually, `"*Foo*".replace(/\x2a/g, '%')` worked for me. What was the problem with that one? Or which browser did it fail in?

Comment: It's highly possible I could have botched something on that one. I just tested it again and it's working - weird. I'm testing in Firefox 3.5 nightlies (Shiretoko) and Epiphany (webkit).

Comment: Also, it could have easily been something that was fixed in the newest nightly. I should have kept the old build around to test in.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try:

```
queryString = inputText.replace(/\*/g, '%');
```

Comment: So simple, yet so hard. Awesome :)

Answer (score 5):

Splitting a string into an array and then joining it back into a string is faster than regular expression replacements:

```
queryString = inputText.split("*").join("%");
```

Comment: I've never seen this approach, but I'll certainly do some of my own testing and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Would need some benchmark, both on CPU and memory... Unless you do replacement on a large text, I doubt we see much speed gain.

Comment: Here's an explanation I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript/441035#441035

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try passwords with a nice touch for remembering

```
str.replace(str.substr(1,str.length-3), str.substr(1,str.length-3).replace(/./g,"*"))
```

The output will be

```
1*********xY
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need a regular expression. You can simply use replaceAll:

```
queryString = inputText.replaceAll("*", "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
queryString = inputText.replace(/[*]/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to hide some digits of a phone numbers

```js
function replacePhoneNumbers(number){
    var cuantos = number.length;
    var tele = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cuantos; i++) {
        if(i < 7){
            tele[i] = number[i].replace(/^\d+$/, "*");
        }
        else{
            tele[i] = number[i];
        }
    }
    
    var full_phone = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < cuantos; i++) {
        full_phone += tele[i];
    }
    return full_phone;
    //return number;
}

var number = replacePhoneNumbers("7533930048");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```