# How to replace underscores with spaces using a regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

How can I replace underscores with spaces using a regex in Javascript?

```
var ZZZ = "This_is_my_name";
```

Comment: Any hint on programming language? Regex doesn't replace anything by itself. `string.replace(/_/, " ")`

Comment: Which language (looks like JavaScript)? This can be done without regex (but not in JavaScript ;)) In VIM: `:%s/_/ /g`

Comment: Regular expressions can’t replace anything. They can only describe some grammar. But many language use regular expressions to search for certain strings. So what language do you use?

Comment: How can I replace underscores with spaces using a regex in Javascript?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If it is a JavaScript code, write this, to have transformed string in `ZZZ2`:

```
var ZZZ = "This_is_my_name";
var ZZZ2 = ZZZ.replace(/_/g, " ");
```

also, you can do it in less efficient, but more funky, way, without using regex:

```
var ZZZ = "This_is_my_name";
var ZZZ2 = ZZZ.split("_").join(" ");
```

Comment: To quote [Crescent Fresh](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441035/1778898) quoting [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/), it is actually more efficient currently doing the latter approach of .split("_").join(" ").

Comment: I agree.  I believe the first method will only replace the first underscore in the string

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze Did you check it? The `g` flag takes care of replacing all occurrences.

Comment: ya.  i had a list of cities, and it only changed the underscore in the first instance.  so i used split join and it worked for me.  but i see everybody else is using the same replace, so it must work properly, but it did not for me.  i ran mine in a for loop to print out all cities and it only worked with first instance.

Comment: @AdamJosephLooze Both of my snippets are compliant with ES3, ES5 (and higher) specs. If you had a problem with the replace method **with a regular expression with a `g` flag** (that flag is important), that may be because of a faulty JS engine implementation or because of a mistake in the code. Could you show me your code, maybe I could help? (maybe with http://jsbin.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not a tool to replace texts inside strings but just something that **can search for patterns inside strings**. You need to provide a context of a programming language to have your solution.

I can tell you that the regex `_` will match the underscore but nothing more.

For example in Groovy you would do something like:

```
"This_is_my_name".replaceAll(/_/," ")
    ===> This is my name
```

but this is just language specific (`replaceAll` method)..

Answer (score 1):

```
var str1="my__st_ri_ng";
var str2=str1.replace(/_/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "_" with " "

The actual implementation depends on your language.

In Perl it would be:

```
s/_/ /g
```

But the truth is, if you are replacing a fixed string with something else, you don't need a regular expression, you can use your language/library's basic string replacement algorithms.

Another possible Perl solution would be:

```
tr/_/ /
```

Comment: You are right. Except the question didn't say anything about JavaScript when I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To replace the underscores with spaces in a string, call the **replaceAll()** method, passing it an underscore and space as parameters, e.g. **str.replaceAll('_', ' ')**. The replaceAll method will return a new string where each underscore is replaced by a space.

```
const str = 'apple_pear_melon';

// ✅ without regular expression
const result1 = str.replaceAll('_', ' ');
console.log(result1); // ️ "apple pear melon"

// ✅ with regular expression
const result2 = str.replace(/_+/g, ' ');
console.log(result2); // ️ "apple pear melon"
```