# using javascript calculated values in less

Tags: javascript, css, less

In LESS I used following code to get the window's height.

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`
```

What I'm getting is a number, but when i add `px` there to have the unit,

```
height: @winheight px;
```

It will compile to something like `height: 910 px`.

I tried to have the unit after the javascript evaluation too. but I got the same result.

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`px
height: @winheight;
...

height:910 px;
```

How can I get `height:910px` there (without the space between number and unit) ?

---

EDIT:

As for the first four results, it creates a string `height:"910px"`, which doesn't render correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply use [string interpolation](http://lesscss.org/#-string-interpolation) and then [escape](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping) from the string using `~`:

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`;

height: ~"@{winheight}px";
```

Comment: I got this error in NodeJs
-- 
JavaScript evaluation error: 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Comment: @Mochamad Lucky Prada you can only evaluate JavaScript in LESS that is compiled client-side

Comment: Is that means the LESS doesn't get the jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

give this code and see what is you get it.

```
@winheight:0px + `$(window).height()'
```

Comment: @Christoph : Rushi put up this answer while I was editing mine so no copying involved

Comment: my bad...feel free to edit your answer so i can remove the -1.

Answer (score 1):

Take `.css(height)` instead of `.height()` - this returns the value + unit.

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing empty space help for you? Try reading the answer of this: [Replacing spaces with underscores in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()+"px"`
height: @winheight;
```

because **.height()** returns only **unit-less pixel value.**
**alternatively** use the following

```
@winheight:`$(window).css("height")`
    height: @winheight;
```

.css("height") returns a value with units

Comment: this returns a string value. but it is not rendered in the browser `height: "910px"`

Comment: @tiran check my updated answer once, please let me know if is working or not

Comment: I got following error when I execute your code in the browser. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultView' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
@winheight:`$(window).height().toString() + "px"`
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work depending on LESS which I do not know well.

Reading the docs this is a possibility.

```
@winheight:0px + `$(window).height()`
```

Comment: this returns a string value. but it is not rendered in the browser height: "910px"

Comment: I have edited my answer after reading the docs. Can you set up a jsFiddle?