# Set height and width to fraction of parents height/width?

Tags: css, less

I'm new to LESS.  Is there a way to get the parent height and width?  I'm trying to set something to be a percentage of the parent.  For instance:

**fictitious pseudo code** *because I have no idea what I'm doing*

```
@myheight: parent.height / 4;
@mywidth: parent.width / 4;

.myRelObject {
    height: @myheight
    width: @mywidth
}
```

The closest I found was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794043/using-javascript-calculated-values-in-less), so if someone can just tell me if/how to get parent height/width I can probably get it from there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LESS for this

```
.myRelObject {
    height: 25%;
    width: 25%;
}
```

edit: I should be more specific, unless the parents have a set height and width you can't get that value until it is rendered in the DOM, so it is better to use vanilla CSS like above.