# Need to access the current url from my LESS file

Tags: javascript, less

I've seen a few [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794043/using-javascript-calculated-values-in-less) of people using javascript from within a LESS file, however I'm unable to reproduce this myself.

I'm looking to have a variable to use for coloring certain and i want that color to change depending on the current directory of the url.

Is this possible? Is there an easier way to go about it?

Comment: Are you compiling the LESS pre-deployment, or are you using `less.js` for client-side compilation?

Comment: It is being compiled pre-deployment