# How to replace all spaces in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have two html text input, out of that what ever user type in first text box that need to reflect on second text box while reflecting it should replace all spaces to semicolon. I did to some extant and it replacing for first space not for all, I think I need to use .each function of Jquery, I have used .each function but I didn't get the result  [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/8YANp/16/)

HTML :

```
Title : <input type="text" id="title"><br/>
Keyword : <input type="text" id="keyword">
```

Jquery:

```
$('#title').keyup(function() {
    var replaceSpace = $(this).val(); 

        var result = replaceSpace.replace(" ", ";");

        $("#keyword").val(result);

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing spaces with underscores in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string)

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
var result = replaceSpace.replace(/ /g, ";");
```

Here, `/ /g` is a regex (regular expression). The flag `g` means global. It causes all matches to be replaced.

Comment: Also worth noting: use `/ +/g` to replace runs of spaces with only one semicolon. Use `/\s/g` to replace all white space characters. Use `/\s+/g` to replace all runs of white spaces.

Comment: Or you could do this: `$("#keyword").val($(this).val().split(' ').join(';'));` if you wanted (for whatever reason) to avoid regexes

Comment: @Kay's edit (http://jsfiddle.net/pLmv7/) is likely the best approach, it easily deals with multiple spaces producing only a single semicolon

Comment: And probably you what to use [`replaceSpace.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) before applying the replace. trim() strips off leading and trailing white spaces.

Comment: `/\s+\S/g` would prevent a semicolon from being added by trailing spaces

Comment: @JasonSperske `/\s+\S/g` drops the first character after a white space.

Comment: This is why I tend to avoid regexes :)

Comment: @JasonSperske, you could change it to `/\s+(?=\S)/g`. (Though `/(?<=\S)\s+(?=\S)/g` works for beginning and end.) There now you can like regexes again.

Comment: I have come here like 100+ times lol

Answer (score 22):

Pure Javascript, without regular expression:

```
var result = replaceSpacesText.split(" ").join("");
```

Comment: any difference in speed compared to the regex?

Comment: Tested - no performance difference, at least worthing attention.

Answer (score 9):

takes care of multiple white spaces and replaces it for a single character

`myString.replace(/\s+/g, "-")`

http://jsfiddle.net/aC5ZW/340/

Answer (score 6):

## VERY EASY:

just use this to replace all white spaces  with `-`:

```
myString.replace(/ /g,"-")
```

Comment: How is this any different than the accepted answer 4 years prior in 2013?

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#title').keyup(function () {
        var replaceSpace = $(this).val();

        var result = replaceSpace.replace(/\s/g, ";");

        $("#keyword").val(result);

    });
```

Since the javascript replace function do not replace 'all', we can make use the regular expression for replacement. As per your need we have to replace all space ie the \s in your string globally. The g character after the regular expressions represents the global replacement. The seond parameter will be the replacement character ie the semicolon.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @badacadabra upadated :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple code for **replace all spaces**

```
var str = 'How are you';
var replaced = str.split(' ').join('');
```

**Out put:** 
Howareyou

Comment: How is this any different than the same answer [2 months prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34925579/9664)?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this as well, for me this has worked (covers most browsers):

```
myString.replace(/[\s\uFEFF\xA0]/g, ';');
```

Inspired by this trim polyfill after hitting some bumps:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim#Polyfill

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following fix for removing Whitespaces with trim and *@* symbol:

```
var result = string.replace(/ /g, '');  // Remove whitespaces with trimmed value
var result = string.replace(/ /g, '@'); // Remove whitespaces with *@* symbol
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer