# Remove white spaces from all <li> tag ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Please I need some help in removing all the white spaces from all the `<li>` tag ids.
The ids are dynamically generated from the title of a podcast rss feeds.
How do I convert all the ids (with white spaces) in the following `<li>` tags:

```
<li id="The Purpose of Commitment"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="Take Your Seat"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="The Power of the Soil"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="Seasons of Silence"> ...some content... </li>
```

into ids (without white spaces). Output example below:

```
<li id="ThePurposeofCommitment"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="TakeYourSeat"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="ThePoweroftheSoil"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="SeasonsofSilence"> ...some content... </li>
```

I have searched this forum and found similar questions asked here:
[how to replace all white spaces in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873002/how-to-replace-all-spaces-in-a-string) and here: [replace all spaces in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with). I don't know how to accomplish this on the `<li>` tags.
I really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: `The ids are dynamically generated from the title of a podcast rss feeds` <-- You should remove the whitespace during this process. Please post how the ids are dynamically generated.

Comment: But if you **HAVE TO** remove them afterwards, you can do that with pure JavaScript using split() and join() as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54658907/remove-white-spaces-from-all-li-tag-ids/#answer-54659021).

Comment: Spaces are not your only problem... Arbitrary strings might contain special characters (like single or double quotes) - not really appropriate for IDs, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Those IDs should be *formattted* at the point where they are created, not afterwards.

**Your problem are not only spaces...**

You're using arbitrary strings as ID, and that could include words with special characters, like i.e:  `Let's Code`   → You **don't want the ID to be `id="Let'sCode"`** ← notice the `'`

### Solution?

Replace everything other than a letter, digit or underscore (regex token: `\W`) - **with underscore**.

```js
$("li[id]").prop('id', (i, id) => id.replace(/\W/g, '_'));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="Let's Code"> WARNING! QUOTES! </li>
  <li id="The Purpose of Commitment"> ...some content... </li>
</ul>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Or by using *vanilla* JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li[id]').forEach(el => el.id = el.id.replace(/\W/g, '_'));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="Let's Code"> WARNING! QUOTES! </li>
  <li id="The Purpose of Commitment"> ...some content... </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great answer. I tested the vanilla JS one. It's maybe worth noting that the JS will need to be inside something like window.onload = function(){} for it to work. The OP mightn't know this.

Comment: Thank you @Sarah ! Window.load is not necessary (we're talking about DOM Elements here). Placing the `<script>` tags where appropriate (right before the closing body tag) is enough. What OP needs to take care is that 1. the replacement takes place at LI creation 2. or inside a callback, after a script finishes with the LI creation.

Comment: Oh yes. Sorry I meant  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {}); but nevermind you're right :)

Comment: @Sarah :) yes DOMContentLoaded, or `jQuery($=>{/*doc(ument) you are ready :)*/})` in jQuery. Thx

Comment: that's exactly it :)

Answer (score 1):

**`The ids are dynamically generated from the title of a podcast rss feeds`** <-- You should remove the white-spaces during this process.

---

But if you **HAVE TO** remove them afterwards, you can do that with pure JavaScript using a simple `split()` and `join()` approach like this:

```
let lists = document.querySelectorAll("#someUl li");
lists.forEach(list => list.id = list.id.split(" ").join(""));
```

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
/* JavaScript */

let lists = document.querySelectorAll("#someUl li");

lists.forEach(list => list.id = list.id.split(" ").join(""));
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<ul id="someUl">
  <li id="The Purpose of Commitment"> ...some content... </li>
  <li id="Take Your Seat"> ...some content... </li>
  <li id="The Power of the Soil"> ...some content... </li>
  <li id="Seasons of Silence"> ...some content... </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain Javascript and a regex to replace any number of spaces with nothing:

```
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  li.id = li.id.replace(/\s*/g, '');
});
```

Here is an example which also prints the ids after the transformation:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  li.id = li.id.replace(/\s*/g, '');
});

console.log('ids:');
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  console.log(li.id);
});
```

```html
<li id="The Purpose of Commitment"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="Take Your Seat"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="The Power of the Soil"> ...some content... </li>
<li id="Seasons of Silence"> ...some content... </li>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you reference the parent elements inner html and assign it to a js variable you can use a `.replace()` method to remove the white space and reassign it to the parent.

There may be better ways to do this as I'm quite new myself but I would Google `document.getElementbyid().innerhtml`.