# how to find in table all possible result jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code for finding multiple words in a table but it's not yet perfect.
what if i inputted those multiple words not in order? for example the "John Lennon 151 sf"
and "paul mccartney 753 tj" and i typed the word "lennon 753 tj" the result should be the two of them. but the result that i received is the row of john lennon only..

here's my code

```
<input id="emp_search" />
<input id="search" type="button" value="search" />
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>number</th>
       <th>letters</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>John</td>
       <td>Lennon</td>
       <td>151</td>
       <td>sf</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Paul</td>
       <td>McCartney</td>
       <td>753</td>
       <td>tj</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>George</td>
       <td>Harrison</td>
       <td>24</td>
       <td>ge</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>Ringo</td>
       <td>Starr</td>
       <td>26</td>
       <td>hg</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

and here is..

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}
jQuery(function ($) {
    ///search this table
    $(' #search ').click(function () {
        var searchthis = new RegExp($(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/\s+/, '|'), 'i');
        $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
            var text = $.trim($(this).text());
            $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
        });
    });
});
```

and what will i add to my jquery? thanks in advance :)

http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/5/

Comment: I think it was solved in your previous post itself http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6nzC/10/

Comment: @arun it's not working when i want to search one person. and also the band name  beatles. like "John beatles"

Comment: @Vincent if you search for `John Beatles` it will display all the rows as `Beatles` is present in all of them http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6nzC/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Problem is in your regex `.replace(/\s+/, '|')`

Replace this `.replace(/\s+/, '|')` by this `.replace(/ /g,"|")`

Fixed fiddle : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ANLgD/9/)

[Replacing spaces with underscores in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript#answer-441035)

**Edit :**  Forgot to update the demo.... now I updated

Comment: how about this? http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/8/
with all the same band name. beatles but if i searched "john starr beatles"

Comment: the result should be 2 rows

Comment: "the result should be the two of them", why this sentence should not apply to the band?

Comment: Well :) Now, try the above demo with "lennon ", then check this suggestion `.replace(/ /g,"|")` with "lennon   paul" (add several whitespaces between the names). Both does not work.

Comment: im having also a problem. with Male and Female, when i tried to search the male , the female is also displayed, because the female has "male" characters in it.

Comment: @rynhe try searching "male"

Comment: @Vincent This situation (searching for "male") works as expected. It's hard to help if you change your direction everytime. Resolve the actual problem (make a choice between AND and OR), close this topic, then post a new question ("how to search for "begins with"?").

Comment: oh im sorry.. i was just thinking of the possible results.

Comment: @Vincent What are you talking about now :D You think about things? You see dead people? Take it easy, I'm joking. I mean, try to focus on one problem at a time, otherwise this discussion will never end ;)

Comment: hahaha. ok. i'm going to create a new post. with this male and female thing haha

Comment: Try to resolve this problem by yourself before posting a new question, otherwise you're likely to be downvoted. Hint to search for leading chars : `/^lennon/i` (`^` stands for "begins with").

Comment: well i've tried that. still not working :( I'm just new in programming to be honest.

Comment: @Vincent Well, hold on, post a new question with something you've tried :)

Comment: @wared here is my new post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217409/search-in-a-table-with-multiple-words/

Answer (score 3):

Your replace gives : `/lennon|753 tj/i`. Use the global flag :

```
$('#emp_search').val().replace(/\s+/g, '|')
```

Moreover, don't forget to trim the input ("lennon " currently gives `/lennon|/i`) :

```
$.trim($('#emp_search').val()).replace(/\s+/g, '|')
```

Here is a demo which actually works : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/93jEY/.

Finally, you have forgotten to use `escape` :

```
RegExp.escape($.trim($('#emp_search').val()).replace(/\s+/g, '|'))
```

Comment: what if a i have more column containing all beatles. i want to search paul beatles. the result should be only paul mccartney

Comment: "the result should be the two of them", why this sentence should not apply to the band?

Comment: because. what if..... i have the same first and last name but different band name