# search in a table with multiple words

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a code in searching multiple words in jquery. but i have a problem on searching the word male and female. when i inputted the word male, the display result is female and male, because the word female contains "Fe" + "male" characters , how will i fix this problem.
when i typed the male , it should only display the male. and the female word will be only displayed when i typed "Male Female" or "Female"

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
RegExp.escape = function (s) {
    return s.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
};
}
jQuery(function ($) {
///search this table
$(' #search ').click(function () {
    var searchthis = new RegExp($(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|"), 'i');
    $("table").find("tr").slice(1).each(function (index) {
      //  var text = $(this).find("td").text().toLowerCase().trim();
        var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        $(this).toggle(searchthis.test(text));
    });
});
});
```

here is my demo
**http://jsfiddle.net/wind_chime18/ANLgD/10/**

Comment: Could you clarify by providing a bunch of examples using AND and OR like : "a line should contain : john OR male OR female"? This will help you in defining exactly what you want. Please update your question rather than adding new comments.

Comment: ok sir. it is already ok now sir. thanks for the advice :)

Comment: oopppps .. the bounty is not valid. i was just testing it. sorry

Comment: Glad to know your done :D I hope everything is clear for you. Keep enjoying :)

Comment: @Vincent are you not going to reward the bounty? It goes to waste if not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\b` to detect word boundaries:

```
var s = "There are two sexes: female and male. males are blue, females are red";
s = s.replace(/\bmale\b/g, "smurf");
console.log(s);
// There are two sexes: female and smurf. males are blue, females are red"
// both female, males and females don't match \bmale\b
```

Without `\b` you would get:

```
There are two sexes: fesmurf and smurf. smurfs are blue, fesmurfs are red
```

If you change this line:

```
var searchthis = new RegExp($(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|"), 'i');
```

to

```
var searchthis = new RegExp("\\b" + $(' #emp_search ').val().replace(/ /g,"|") + "\\b", 'i');
```

it *works* but that means that searching for `Jo` will not give you `John` either.

Comment: i really should put the "\bmale\b"?

Comment: sorry im just new in programming. have you seen my jsfiddle?

Comment: pst. hey? still there?

Comment: @Vincent You should upvote sometimes instead of whispering like that, this is annoying and doesn't encourage folks to help you at all :D