# How to remove double underscore using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

How do I remove double or multiple underscores in a string using JavaScript?

E.g.

`stack__overflow___website`

I will need to eliminate the `__` and replace it with a single `_`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `replace()` with a regex to match consecutive underscores:

```
'stack__overflow___website'.replace(/_+/g, '_')
```

Comment: thank you!

here's what i got from your code

var _removeUnderscores = _convertLowerCase.replace(/_+/g, '_');

Answer (score 3):

```
var myString = "stack__overflow___website",
    myFormattedString = myString.split('__').join('_');
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I wonder what the performance considerations are here.

Comment: this is only one case.

Comment: they are supposed to be better. yet downvoted :s

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript