# remove spaces from anchor href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to replace spaces in hyperlink text with hyphen(-). 
 Below is my anchor tag :

```
<a href="${user.workstation}"></a>
```

and I want some something like this :

```
<a href="replace(${user.workstation}, " ", "-")"></a>
```

Please advice.

Comment: javascript has simple function called `.replace` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace cant you  use that ?

Comment: Try, str.replace, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: use this link ----->  http://jsbin.com/zimimozetu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks @Bek, I will try this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing spaces with underscores in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441018/replacing-spaces-with-underscores-in-javascript)

Comment: @ShivSingh : It's not.  In my case I wanted as inline as I mentioned above in my example code.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

```
var corrected = $('a').attr('href').replace(/ /g,'-');
$('a').attr('href' , corrected );
```

The [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method searches a string for a specified value, or a regular expression, and returns a new string where the specified values are replaced.

**g** Perform a [global match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)

Comment: Is it possible to use this kind of code as inline  as I have mentioned in above example ?